# TFS: execute console application after get latest version

Tags: c#, tfs

if someone does a 'get latest version' in visual studio (team explorer) of a project in Team Foundation Server - is it possible to execute a console application automatically after this operation? The goal is that the local database is updated with new scripts every time a developer gets the latest version of the source code. So the question is how to do a post update like in subversion?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd be more inclined to go the other way - have the console application that updates the database do the get itself, and change process so that all you do is run the console application. This will ensure the correct sequencing of steps.

To have the console application do the get, you can either look into the various ways of calling the TFS SDK / API - or, much more simply, have it [execute a `tf get` with appropriate parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fx7sdeyf.aspx).